# Count the number of substrings with the same 0 and 1

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that `S` is a string containing only 0 and 1, and the length of `S` does not exceed `10^6`. I would like to count how many substrings of `S` in which the number of 0 is equal to the number of 1.
The provided code is as follows:

```
#define MAXN 1000000
int count_01(std::string s) {
    int * F = new int[2 * MAXN + 1];
    memset(F, 0, sizeof(int) * (2 * MAXN + 1));
    F[0] = 1;
    
    int sum = 0, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)s.length(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == '0')
            --sum;
        else
            ++sum;
        if (sum >= 0) {
            count += F[sum];
            ++F[sum];
        }
        else {
            count += F[MAXN + abs(sum)];
            ++F[MAXN + abs(sum)];
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

If I understand it correctly, it relies on the difference between the numbers of 0 and 1 when we traverse the string, and add the `count`. In particular, for `i <= j`, Let `A[i,j]` and `B[i,j]` be the numbers of 0 and 1 in `[i,j]` respectively. Then since

> A[i, j] = A[1, j] - A[1, i - 1],
>
> B[i, j] = B[1, j] - B[1, i - 1],

for `[i, j]` satisfying the required condition `A[i, j] = B[i, j]`, we must have

> A[1, j] - B[1, j] = A[1, i - 1] - B[1, i - 1] (*).

This means we only look at the difference between the numbers of 0 and 1 and count how many times this number occurs. Is my reasoning correct?

I don't understand how `count` works. For example, suppose `S = '0101` and `i = 3` (the end of string). At this time, `count = count + F[0]`, which is 4 because `count = 2` and `F[0] = 2`. Are we double-counting? Should we increment `count` by only 1 according to (*)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For down-voter, can you explain? If the question was already asked or should be in another forum, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but a simpler way of saying it is that if a substring from *i* to *j* has the same number of 0s and 1s, then the cumulative difference at *i* is the same as the cumulative difference at *j*. If you prefer visual analogies, think of a 1 as a step up and a 0 as a step down; the cumulative difference at point *i* is the height at point *i* and a substring with equal counts is a line whose endpoints are at the same height.

F[*sum*] at any point in the traverse is the number of previous points at exactly height *sum*, which is the current height. So its the number of starting points of balanced segmentd ending at the current point; each of these corresponds to a balanced substring ending at the current point. Since we only visit each point once, none of these strings has been counted before and none will be counted again.

Answer (score 1):

F[] is virtually folded array with range [-MAXN..MAXN], containing quantities of cumulative differences - i.e. how many times every possible difference value has been met so far.

For every new difference `sum` (we stay at the end of substring) we have to add `F[sum]` to the `count`, because there is `F[sum]` possible valid substring start positions.

For your example: there are two starting positions with zero difference (0 and 2), that is why final step adds two variants (from 4 possible: `01, 10, 01, 0101`)